# why I can't run my median program, I really don't get it

Tags: python

I really don't know that I have made two while loops, but when I ran it, it only showed first loop.

```
do_caculation = True
while(do_caculation):
        while(True):
                stat_number_count = 0
                stat_number_sum = 0
                stat_number_average = 0
                stat_number_maximum = 0
                stat_number_minimum = 0
                state_number_range = 0

                try:
                    stat_number_name= input("What is the name of the file: ")
                    stat_number = open(stat_number_name,"r")
                    raw = stat_number.readlines()
                    raws = []

                    for number in raw:
                        raws.append(int(number))        

                    stat_number_count = sum(raws)
                    stat_number_sum = len(raws)
                    stat_number_maximum = max(raws)
                    stat_number_minimum = min(raws)

                    stat_number_range = stat_number_maximum - stat_number_minimum 
                    stat_number_average = stat_number_count/stat_number_sum









                except Exception as error:
                    print("An error occurred reading", stat_number_name)

                else:
                    print("File name:", stat_number_name)
                    print("Sum:", stat_number_sum)
                    print("Count:", stat_number_count)
                    print("Average:", stat_number_average)
                    print("Maximum:", stat_number_maximum)
                    print("Minimum:", stat_number_minimum)
                    print("Range:", stat_number_range)








        while(True):
                def median(raws):
                    n = len(raws)
                if n < 1:
                        print ("XD")
                if n % 2 == 1:
                        SB = sorted(raws)[n//2]
                        print (SB)
                else:
                    print (sum(sorted(raws)[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0
```

Comment: The function definition for median is both misplaced (should be at the top) and not properly indented.  There's no point in having a function definition in a loop.  Put it where it belongs and you'd find out about the indentation problem a lot sooner.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: There's plenty more that's wrong, as well.  Basically, this looks like you've tried to write too much code at once.  It's a lot better to implement one feature at a time.  For example, you could simply start by defining that `median()` function and testing it to verify that it works. (Right now, it doesn't.) Once you've done that, you can use the function with confidence.  Each new feature will be like that.  When you get an error, it's in the last bit you edited and you can focus on fixing that that one bit.

Answer (score 1):

You never exit the first `while` loop, so you never execute the second loop.

From this code it doesn't look like you really understand what a `while` loop does. The block of code inside the loop will continue to run until the condition you gave it is no longer true. You're using

```
while(True)
```

which can never possibly be false. Thus, the loop will always run unless broken by a `break` statement or an exception - and an exception isn't an option in this case, because if one occurs you're catching it and simply printing a String to the console.

You need to have some way to escape your `while` loop. I suggest removing it entirely - it doesn't seem necessary here. Or you can change the condition for the loop from `True` to something that might eventually be false. Or you can put a `break` statement inside the loop. Or a couple of other possibilities, but you see what I'm getting at.

Comment: oh damn, i forgot to put Break